# How to generalize Poisson correction for multiple populations?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I have an interesting problem which I am trying to mathematically formulate and solve.

Consider the following "single population" problem statement.

You throw n blue marbles randomly (i.e. uniform) onto m wells. Subsequently, you are allowed to observe whether each of the wells have **at least** 1 marble in it. Therefore, using the **known** quantities: (1) number of wells, m and (2) number of empty wells; estimate the total number of blue marbles.

The above problem can be solved using binomial and poisson statistics like so:
[image]

I am trying to extend this solution to multiple populations. For example when there are blue and red marbles.

[image]

Intuitively, I believe statistics should be able to help with this generalization. For example, if m=100 and we observe n_blue=10, n_red=50 and n_purple=5, then I would expect more red marbles within the purple observations.

Nevertheless, I am struggling to formulate the problem and estimate any parameters because I am running into too many unknowns (and non-linear equations). Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Update:

Thanks [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) for the answer. Moreover, I am trying to tackle another version which is similar the one above with a caveat. Please see below.

[image]

Comment: How can this wonderfully illustrated question not have attracted a single upvote over the course of two hours?!

Comment: So, based on the illustration, I take "$50/50$" to mean not that you can make a fourth type of observation called "$50/50$", but that for equal numbers there's a $50/50$ chance that you'll observe the well as blue or as red?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You’re overthinking this. You have two independent colours and you want to estimate how many marbles there are of each. Just apply the single-colour method to each of them. The estimator for the blue marbles is $\hat n_1=-m\ln(E+R)$, with $E+R$ the number of wells that are empty of blue marbles, and the estimator for the red marbles is $\hat n_2=-m\ln(E+B)$, with $E+B$ the number of wells that are empty of red marbles.

Comment: You're right! The reason why I was overthinking was because my next step was to figure out a slightly harder problem (see edit).